# How to install parallel (two) redmine instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, redmine

I am attempting to set up a separate (parallel) redmine instance.
Unfortunately, I don't know much about rails and the ruby environment.

Is this even possible?

Assuming it is...
I am running into problems with what seems to be the implied allowable environments --

```
  production 
  development
  test
```

Are these somehow cast in stone?
I had originally thought I would use the "test" config,
but because it is erased under some circumstances, it is unsuitable.
I wanted to preserve development for possible other use.
So I am trying to add a new environment.
Is this possible? (by that I mean reasonably easily achieved)

Done so far:

```
  set up new redmine directory hierarchy at /opt/xxx_test/redmine-4.1.1
  set up new mysql database xxx_test with new user xxx_test for xxx_test
  modified config/database.yml to contain only xxx_test (no production, development, or test)
  generated new secret token
```

When the original (primary) redmine was installed, it was installed with:

```
  bundle config set without 'development test'
  bundle install
```

When I now do:

```
  bundle config set without 'production development test'
```

I get the message:

```
'Your application has set without to "development:test". This will override the global value you are currently setting'
```

Where is this set, and how do I change it?

When I do the "Database schema objects migration" (installation step 6)
I get an error that seems to imply it is accessing the already installed "production" environment:

```
RAILS_ENV=xxx_test bundle exec rake db:migrate
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:
  
  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'xxx_test'@'localhost' to database 'redmine'
```

Where / how are these development/test/production "things" set to true/false?
I see nothing in config/environment or config/environments/*.rb

Comment: Why do you want to run two instances of the same application on the same server in the first place? IMO it is much easier to clone the first instance, change the configuration and run the clone on another server. Apart from that, you can add as many environments as you want and can name them as you want (production_1, production_2). You just need to add an additional environment file and set the RAILS_ENV accordingly.

Comment: We have only one server available, and have staff who are experimenting with what makes the most sense in how we deal with some projects.  It was my understanding that running on the same instance causes problems with shared files such as the log file and uploaded files.

Comment: You can run as much redmines under different linux users using RVM, apache virtual hosts which can either run proxy to different ports or run via passenger module.

Comment: @Aleksandar I don't understand.  /etc/apache2/mods-available.conf/passenger.conf specifies PassengerUser, PassengerGroup, PassengerUserSwitching, but no path to the redmine it should be running.  How does it get the path to the redmine it should run?  /etc/apache2/rubies/xxx.include specifies RailsBaseURI /redmine and /redmine-test and one PerlLoadModule Apache2::Redmine

Comment: @GaryAitken it's configured on per virtual host basis, see my book on Redmine...

Answer (score 0):

The script below is a hand-tweaked version of what I ended up doing to establish a second redmine on one server.  It has not been tested but should provide reasonable guidance.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script to set up a second redmine instance running on the same server
# Note:
#   This script has been tweaked for general application and may contain errors
# Helpful References:
#   https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall
#   https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/intro.html
# For rvm 1.29.10, redmine 4.1.1, passenger 5.3, apache 2.4.29
 
# Add user for new redmine to run as
sudo adduser --debug --shell /bin/bash --gecos 'redmine user 2' redmine_usr_2
sudo usermod -a -G rvm redmine_usr_2
# pw: <redmine-2-pw>
 
# Add database for second redmine to mysql
mysql -u <mysql-maint-acct> -p<mysql-maint-pw>
mysql> create database redmine_two character set utf8mb4;
mysql> create user 'redmine_usr_2'@'localhost' identified by '<redmine-2-pw';
mysql> grant all privileges on redmine_two.* to 'redmine_usr_2'@'localhost';
mysql> quit;
 
# Create the directory for the second instance redmine program
# Can't use the existing production version because some things,
# such as logs and uploaded files, also reside there
# The file .ruby-version contains "4.1.1" and prevents rvm from
# spewing messages about incompatible ruby version.
sudo -i -u redmine_usr_2
ln -s /opt/redmine/redmine-4.1.1.tar.gz
tar xf redmine-4.1.1.tar.gz
ln -s redmine-4.1.1 redmine_2
cd redmine_2
cp -p /opt/redmine/redmine/.ruby-version .

# Step 3 Database connection configuration
# Database connection is set up for a ruby environment named "redmine_2_env"
cd ~/redmine_2/config
sed -e "/^production:/,/encoding:/ s/database: redmine/database: redmine_two/" -e "/^production:/,/encoding:/ s/username: root/usern
ame: redmine_usr_2/" -e "/^production:/,/encoding:/ s/password: \"\"/password: \"<redmine-2-pw>\"/" -e "/^production:/ s/production/
redmine_2_env/" -e "/^development:/,/encoding:/ s/^/#/" -e "/^test:/,/encoding:/ s/^/#/" database.yml.example >database.yml_new
cp -p database.yml_new database.yml

# Environment configuration
cd ~/redmine_2/config/environments
cp -p production.rb redmine_2_env.rb

# Step 4 Dependencies installation
cd ~/redmine_2
bundle install
# Note that this may install some new (updated) gems

# Step 5 Session store secret generation
cd ~/redmine_2
bundle exec rake generate_secret_token

# Step 6 Database schema objects migration
cd ~/redmine_2
RAILS_ENV=redmine_2_env bundle exec rake db:migrate

# Step 7 Database default data set
cd ~/redmine_2
RAILS_ENV=redmine_2_env REDMINE_LANG=en bundle exec rake redmine:load_default_data

# Step 8 File system permissions
cd ~/redmine_2
# Note that on install the directories below actually already existed
# but doing the mkdir on an existing directory will be fine.
mkdir -p tmp tmp/pdf public/plugin_assets

## Step 9 Test the installation
## Use lynx because I don't have a local web browser.
# Note!!! This part of the script must be tested by hand, so is commented out
#cd ~/redmine_2
#bundle exec rails server webrick -e redmine_2_env &
## sudo aptitude install lynx
#lynx http://localhost:3000/
## This shows the redmine startup page

# Install plugins
cd ~/redmine_2
git clone -b stable https://github.com/AlphaNodes/additionals.git plugins/additionals
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=redmine_2_env
exit

# Add new url to apache
# This includes the options necessary to configure PhusionPassenger
#   See: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/
# 
# /var/www/html
sudo ln -s /home/redmine_usr_2/redmine_2/public /var/www/html/redmine-site-2-url

# /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf specifies these global parameters:
#   PassengerRoot /opt/passenger/passenger-stable-5.3
#   PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/wrappers/ruby
#   PassengerUserSwitching on
#   PassengerUser <passenger-default-ruby-user>
#   PassengerGroup <passenger-default-ruby-group>
#   PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
# /etc/apache2/rubies/redmine-site-1.include specifies app-specific parameters for redmine site-1:
#        <directory  /var/www/html/redmine-site-1-url>
#            RailsBaseURI /redmine-site-1-url
#            PassengerAppRoot /opt/redmine/redmine
#            PassengerAppEnv production
#            PassengerAppGroupName production
#        </Directory>
# /etc/apache2/rubies/redmine-site-2.include app-specific parameters for redmine site-2:
#        <Directory /var/www/html/redmine-site-2-url>
#            PassengerAppRoot /home/redmine_usr_2/redmine_2
#            PassengerAppEnv redmine_2_env
#            PassengerAppGroupName redmine_2
#            RailsBaseURI /redmine-site-2-url
#            PassengerUser redmine_usr_2
#            PassengerGroup redmine_usr_2
#            PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
#        </Directory>
#   
cd /etc/apache2/rubies
# Edit redmine-site-1.include to be consistent with the above redmine-site-1 contents
# Create redmine-site-2.include to be consistent with the above redmine-site-2 contents
sudo cp -p redmine-site-1.include redmine-site-1.include_org
sudo sh -c 'sed -e "/URI \/issues/ a\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ PassengerAppRoot /opt/redmine/redmine\n            PassengerAppEnv produ
ction\n            PassengerAppGroupName production" redmine-site-1.include_org >redmine-site-1.include_new'
sudo cp -p redmine-site-1.include_new redmine-site-1.include
sudo sh -c 'cat - <<EOF > /etc/apache2/rubies/redmine-site-2.include
# /etc/apache2/rubies/redmine-site-2.include
        <Directory /var/www/html/redmine-site-2-url>
            PassengerAppRoot /home/redmine_usr_2/redmine_2
            PassengerAppEnv redmine_2_env
            PassengerAppGroupName redmine_2
            RailsBaseURI /redmine-site-2-url
            PassengerUser redmine_usr_2
            PassengerGroup redmine_usr_2
            PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
        </Directory>
EOF'
# tweak the existing apache redmine site.conf to include
# the /etc/apache2/rubies include file for the new site
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo cp -p redmine-sites.conf redmine-sites.conf_org
sudo sh -c 'sed -e "/redmine-site-1.include/ a\ \ \ \ Include rubies/redmine-site-2.include" redmine-sites.conf_org >redmine-sites.c
onf_new'
sudo cp -p redmine-sites.conf_new redmine-sites.conf
sudo cp -p redmine-sites-le-ssl.conf redmine-sites-le-ssl.conf_org
sudo sh -c 'sed -e "/redmine-site-1.include/ a\ \ \ \ Include rubies/redmine-site-2.include" redmine-sites-le-ssl.conf_org >redmine-
sites-le-ssl.conf_new'
sudo cp -p redmine-sites-le-ssl.conf_new redmine-sites-le-ssl.conf
sudo apache2ctl restart
```